# When are the Sitecore MVPs announced? How are MVPs typically notified?

Tags: community, mvp

I'm curious when the Sitecore MVPs will be announced and for those of you that are currently MVP's, how were you notified in the past?

Does Sitecore reach out to you directly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't involve any sitecore related technology at all. If he wants to know about the MVP announcements, he should follow twitter

Comment: Personally, I think it is a good community question for those who want to quickly find some info on MVP announcements

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based - the only people who *know* when MVPs will be announced is Sitecore themselves. Everyone else is just guessing (based on previous years) until an official announcement is made.

Comment: As an MVP outsider like many of us that were probably nominated, this is a common question I bet most of us have.  It's probably only a question MVP's can answer.  When are Sitecore MVP's announced? Yes probably only Sitecore knows that answer, but they've probably announced that information.  How are MVPs typically notified? I assume there are MVP's on this community that know how they were notified in previous years.  I don't see where that would lead to opinion answers? StackExchange isn't all technical, there is room for community Sitecore topics as well.

Comment: I appreciate @DylanYoung question and comment. I feel that many current Sitecore MVPs (of which I am not) may want to remember that as a Sitecore community, we look for experts that "provide valuable online and offline expertise that enriches the community experience and makes a difference" and "individuals with a passion for sharing their knowledge and expertise through active participation in online and offline Sitecore communities". The Sitecore StackExchange is an example of one of those forums. The community should promote those striving to succeed, not discourage them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at [the official MVP website](https://mvp.sitecore.com/become-an-mvp) you can see the question about the timeline there:

> **What is the timeline of the selection process?**
>
> The nomination is open during November for the exact dates please
>   follow https://twitter.com/SitecoreMVP. We will review all the
>   nominations and recommendations during December and we will finalize
>   the award winners early January. The announcement of the Sitecore MVP
>   Awards will be by the end of January.

The press release is scheduled for the 31st January and every nominee will get an email couple of days before the announcement even if not awarded.

Comment: Tamas I haven't had any mail yet

Comment: Drazen, I know it is frustrating, should be sent out today.

Comment: Official announcement is out and is available at http://www.sitecore.net/en/company/press-and-media/press-releases/2017/01/sitecore-names-its-2017-most-valuable-professionals

Answer (score 3):

On the last year MVPs were announced at beginning of February. Last years was an official press release on Sitecore website but all MVP received an email few days before official press release.

Comment: For 2018, MVPs were announced on January 31, 2018.