# What should I expect in the MVP nomination or first-time application process?

Tags: mvp

There has been a considerable amount of traffic on Sitecore Slack Chat, Sitecore Stack Exchange, and even Twitter as to what should people experience when submitting applications or nominations for MVPs.

**Frequently asked questions:**

- Is there value in receiving an email notification after submitting a nomination for someone else.
- Do I have to be recommended **before** submitting my own nomination if I'm not currently an MVP?
- What is the appropriate time period of activities I should list? Current calendar year only?
- How should I seek out nominations from the MVPs in the community?

What process has Sitecore outlined for the community?

Comment: Not sure the first FAQ is about submitting a “recommendation” for someone else. If it is not, please ignore this comment.

Comment: Here is the guideline from the Sitecore community, have a look on it. https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/13/t/10742

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The MVP nomination process is outlined on the [Sitecore MVP website](https://mvp.sitecore.net/become-an-mvp) and it is also worth reading previous question on [How to become a Sitecore MVP](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/5796/135).

### Nomination

The MVP process for 2019 has changed and you must be nominated by an existing MVP or a Sitecore employee before you can apply. Once you have been nominated you will receive an invitation by email, allowing you to create an account and start the application process on the [MVP website](https://mvp.sitecore.com/application).

Existing MVPs will receive an email automatically inviting them to create an account, they do not need to be nominated by another MVP or Sitecore employee.

### Recommendations

Due to the above change, you **must** be [recommended by at least one existing MVP or Sitecore employee](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/2294/135) before you are invited to apply. However, you will not receive an email notification when/if you receive *any further* recommendations, it will however be saved. Whether "there is any value in receiving email notifications" is subjective.

If you are seeking out recommendations then the best way is to do this organically by being active within the community. The previous questions on [How to be Recommended to be a Sitecore MVP](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/2294/135) and [How to become a Sitecore MVP?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/5796/135) has a lot of useful information already.

Any further recommendations can be sent in at any time up to the close of the nomination process.

### Invitation and Recommendation Process

Existing MVPs can log into the site and click on the "Invite & Recommendation" tab, and then fill in the details of the person you are recommending. You will require the following details:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Motivation (Why do you believe this person is eligible for the Sitecore MVP title?)

### Application

In terms of time period of activities to list; the MVP award is an annual award and as such it would make sense that current year of activity is what is taken into account. From my experience, if you applying for your first MVP then you should list *all relevant* history and activity that you feel may help your nomination, but anything older than 18 months is unlikely to be considered. For repeat MVPs, I personally have taken the view that it is based on the previous 12 months activity although I may stretch this to the past 12-15 months if it is highly relevant.

My understanding is that the process has a degree of flexibility built into it so there are no hard and fast rules but continued contribution throughout the whole year is a requirement. If you feel it strengthens your nomination then you should include it.

### Application Process

The general process for the application:

1. Seek out at least one recommendation from an existing MVP or Sitecore employee and have them invite you to apply
2. Once you have been nominated, you will receive an invitation email with a link to create an account
3. Fill out the application for your MVP nomination. You will receive an confirmation email that it was submitted successfully.
4. Those that are recommending you should do so by logging into the application site and using the "Invite & Recommendation" tab. Remember to provide them the email address you are using in your application to make it easier. You will *not* receive further emails you have been recommended after the initial invitation.
5. Wait whilst nominations and recommendations are reviewed during December and January
6. MVPs are [generally announced](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/3848/135) at the end of January. If you are awarded the MVP award then remember to wait until after the official Sitecore announcement before publicizing on social media.

[image: MVP application process]

Comment: Hello @jammykam, could you please let us know when the invitation email process starts? Is it from the same November month or we can receive it before that?

Comment: It should be noted that nominations are not required this year (2021). Anyone can apply here: https://mvp.sitecore.com/Application

Answer (score 5):

The procedure is the same for all the Sitecore MVP types.

In a nutshell:

- You work actively offline and online with community in your free time for the whole year
- In November you ask either one of the existing MVPs or Sitecore employees for recommendation
- If you are recommended, you need to fill the application form
- your application is reviewed
- And at the end of January, MVPs for the next year are announced.

If you want to be a **Sitecore Commerce MVP**, you should focus your activities on:

- writing **Sitecore Commerce** related blog posts,
- giving **Sitecore Commerce** related presentations,
- recording **Sitecore Commerce** related Youtube videos,
- **Sitecore Commerce** related related questions here on SSE,
- any other **Sitecore Commerce** related community activities .

More general information can be found in:

- [How to become a Sitecore MVP?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/how-to-become-a-sitecore-mvp)
- [Is it worth to spent hours and hours of personal time to became a Sitecore MVP?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20891/is-it-worth-to-spent-hours-and-hours-of-personal-time-to-became-a-sitecore-mvp/20893)
- [What should I expect in the MVP nomination or first-time application process?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/what-should-i-expect-in-the-mvp-nomination-or-first-time-application-process)
- [What information is needed for the Sitecore MVP application?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14790/what-information-is-needed-for-the-sitecore-mvp-application)
- [MVP Nominations - What should NOT be added in the forms during nomination process?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/mvp-nominations-what-should-not-be-added-in-the-forms-during-nomination-proces)

Comment: Please note that as of 2021 there is no Commerce category anymore.

Answer (score 5):

**AUTHOR NOTE:** *This answer was previously for a question specifically about what the requirements were for a Commerce MVP, and was merged here. This is why it does not seem to directly address the question.*

**UPDATE NOV. 2020:** There is no longer a Commerce MVP category starting with the current nomination process in November 2020.

---

### What is required to become a Commerce MVP?

On the official Sitecore MVP website, there is a page called [About](https://mvp.sitecore.com/about). At this time, the requirements for Sitecore Commerce are written as follows:

> An individual who actively participates in online and offline communities to share their Sitecore Experience Commerce knowledge and expertise with developers, other Sitecore partners and customers.
>
> **Qualities we are considering when selecting a Commerce MVP:**
>
> - Original quality content e.g.: blog posts, podcasts, videos
> - Community.sitecore.net Forum answers
> - Active at the Sitecore Slack channels
> - Involvement at the Sitecore Stack Exchange
> - Contribution to an open source module
> - Speaking at events like User Groups or Symposium
> - Participate in conversations on Social Media
> - Provide regular product feedback

Comment: Please note that as of 2021 there is no Commerce category anymore.

Comment: Good call out Tamas, I've updated my answer to provide a clarification