# Is it worth to spent hours and hours of personal time to became a Sitecore MVP?

Tags: mvp

I'm not a Sitecore MVP, however, I know that Sitecore MVPs spent a lot of time (personal time) to produce and share Sitecore related documents, like tutorials, blogs, etc.

Can you guys share your opinion about this topic?

Comment: This is not a "share your opinion" type of site. This is a Question and Answer database.

Comment: Honestly, I asked this question to get other MVPs opinion , which should help other developers whos only goal is to become MVP.  I think this is a valid question and there are great answers.

Comment: We have the Community Forums and Slack for conversation and debate. You could never select one single answer here as "correct".

Comment: To be fair, you shouldn't seek MVP for status or benefits. Instead, forget about becoming an MVP and put all your effort into supporting the community, doing awesome things, and taking part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely worth it. MVPs are very attractive to potential employers, as having a Sitecore  MVP can help bring on additional business. The MVP status is attached to you personally, which means it can be used as part of salary negotiations.

There are also additional benefits for MVPs like discounts to some official sitecore events, accessing pre-release versions of Sitecore and modules.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly to me, if you are asking the question, then the answer for you is no. Being an MVP is not about you, its about the community. It's about making the community better. Making the product better. Helping partners succeed. When I solve an issue, the first thing I think is let's get this out to the community in a blog post, a SE answer or a SUG chat. If you feel like you "need" to work harder than you already are to be an MVP. Then you aren't really don't "want" to be one.

I know a lot of MVPs and one thing they all have in common is that they love the Sitecore community. And are open and honest about the products flaws. They spend their time trying to make it better. The fact that the [top 15 plus people on SE](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) are all MVPs is not by accident. No one makes us answer questions. No one makes them sit on Slack and answer questions. These are long term MVPs who lead the community.

`</rant>`

Answer (score 3):

We shouldn't do voluntary work for any reward. People choose to volunteer to give something back to the community, or to help people who are doing similar stuff by sharing knowledge. It also gives opportunity to develop new skills or build on existing experience and knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

It is primarily an opinion based question but all the information can be found on the MVP Sitecore website.

Taken from the Sitecore MVP Website

- Recognition as a global Sitecore expert and community leader
- Access to early product releases and privileged resources, including direct access to product teams and kick-off webinars
- Exclusive invitations to MVP discussion forums.
- Meet your regional Sitecore team and peers during regional MVP meetings
- Exclusive Invitation to the MVP Summit. The Summit is executive insight to product and company strategy with lots of networking and fun activities.
- Discount at Sitecore events SUGCON, Symposium

More information at [Sitecore MVP Benefits](https://mvp.sitecore.com/benefits)

As @Mark mentioned in his comment, please join the [Sitecore Slack channel](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsJX9PC3m8u-labRn_BNnByR0aiAxPYowN-doed6_t45aPhg/viewform) or the [Sitecore Community forum](https://community.sitecore.net) for additional information.